# How do I send data to a list form from a SharePoint page

Tags: list, javascript, infopath, jquery

I have a page that displays data from several lists and has links to a list form which open in a modal popup. I need to send some data to the form to be displayed on the form.  Is there a way I can do this via JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of QueryString. So in each link you can format it like

```
http://siteurl/whateverpage.aspx?ItemId=14
```

Change 14 and dynamically place the Id. Now in your form you can read the query string (using JavaScript or Server Side) and process as required.